# How To Upload Video To Server Using AsyncTask in Android Device

Tags: android

I am trying to upload video to server in android studio, using the arrayList but I have face some problem Multipart entity.addPart() is not supported, I have put the dependencies

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

but it can't work then I'll try to some other way using arrayList to upload video, but it doesn't work. My Code is :

videoUp.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
    $location = "VideoUpload/";
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$file_name);
    echo "Success";
 }else{
    echo "Error";
 } 
?>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button buttonChoose;
    private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 3;
    private String DataParseUrl = "http://192.168.40.114/UploadVideo/videoUp.php";

    private String selectedPath;
    private int serverResponseCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void chooseVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a Video "), SELECT_VIDEO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
                Uri selectedUri = data.getData();
                selectedPath = selectedUri.getPath();
                uploadVideo(selectedPath);
            }
        }
    }
    public void uploadVideo(final String selectedPath) {

        class VideoUP extends AsyncTask<String , String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String videoURL = selectedPath;
                String responseTxt = "";
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myFile", videoURL));
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);
                    File file = new File(selectedPath);

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    responseTxt = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return responseTxt;
            }

           @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Video Uploading Completed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        VideoUP vidup = new VideoUP();
        vidup.execute(selectedPath);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            chooseVideo();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
Activity_Main.xml
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose File"
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoose" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Plz resolve this, And Write Some Script Upload Video file to Server.. Thank's in Advanced.

Comment: you have better libraries for uploading to server..

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the problem within your app or on the webserver?

Comment: The Video file is not upload to the webserver, php code is working fine , also I send a string to insert a records it work, but whether I upload the video this code is not work.. HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);
                    File file = new File(selectedPath);

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    responseTxt = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

Comment: I suppose your code is incomplete. I could not see links between your variables 'nameValuePairs' and 'file' with the service. Please post full code if possible.

Comment: Guys, I need a upload video to the server source code with one action, also it will be done on ArrayList. I have try to do this, but still I face a problem. If you have a source code for uploading a file with one action, so please share the code, I'll be thankful to you...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xawweHlnKFY